# Magento $this->getChildHtml('media') return blank

Tags: magento

Till yesterday all was fine, all of sudden getChildHtml('media') ?> is not returning any html just blank,

checked catelog.xml file

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_media" name="product.info.media" as="media" template="catalog/product/view/media.phtml"/>
```

in view.phtml`<?php  echo $this->getChildHtml('media') ?>`

please help where else I need to check to make it run again

Comment: Hello check it for default theme or any other theme

Comment: try to enable 'template hints'. then can be figured